# show ajax-loader.png on a MVC3 form submit in a Jquerymobile application

Tags: ajax, asp.net-mvc-3, jquery-mobile, icons

I have a mobile  application with MVC3 and Jquerymobile. At form submission (with ajax function) I want to  display loading icon (ajax-loader.png) while submit and redirect.
        Thanks!

my ajax function:

```
 $("#add").click(function () {
    $.validator.unobtrusive.parse($('form'));  //added
    if ($("form").valid()) {
        var IDs = new Array($("#SelectedProduct").val(), $("#SelectedAccount").val(), $("#SelectedProject").val(), $("#SelectedTask").val(), $("#date").val(), $("#duration").val());
        $.ajax({
            url: '@Url.Action("SaveLine", "AddLine")',
            type: 'post',
            data: { ids: IDs },
            dataType: 'json',
            traditional: true,
            success: function (data) {
                if (data.success == true) {
                    $("#ajaxPostMessage").html(data.Success);
                    $("#ajaxPostMessage").addClass('ajaxMessage').slideDown(function () {
                        window.location.href = '@Url.Action("Index", "AddLine")';
                    }).delay(1800)
                }
                else {
                    $("#ajaxPostMessage").html(data.Error);
                    $("#ajaxPostMessage").addClass('ajaxMessage');
                    $("#ajaxPostMessage").show();
                }
            }
        });
    }
    return false;
});
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I would do something like this:

```
Ajax = {
    Submit: function() {
        Ajax.Loading();
        //ajax stuff
        //Ajax.Message('form complete, blah blah');
    },
    Loading: function() {
        $('#ajax').html('ajax-loader.png');
    },
    Message: function(msg) [
        $('#ajax').html(msg);
    }
}
```

Comment: I don't know how to use this. Can look over my code please? Thanks!